# Proof verification - Differentiability of a given class of functions at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

**Following is a problem on differentiability of a class of functions at $0$. I've attached my solution. Please check if there's any gap in my arguments and whether it could be made shorter using some other trick (I've used only the standard $\epsilon-\delta$ technique). Any comments/suggestions are most welcome. Thank you.**

**The Problem :**

Let $r \in \mathbb{Q}$. Consider the class of functions as follows

$
    f(x) = \begin{cases}
        x^r\sin\dfrac{1}{x}, & \text{if } x \neq 0\\
        0, & \text{if } x=0
        \end{cases} 
$

To find out, for what values of $r,$ $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

**My Solution :**

> *Let $r>1.$*

Let us denote the difference quotient $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ by $d_x$.

Now, $|d_x|=\left| \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} \right|=\left| \frac{x^rsin \big(\frac{1}{x}\big)}{x} \right|=\left| x^{r-1}sin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big) \right|$

Since $r \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (1, \infty),$ $r-1 \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (0, \infty)$.

Then $|d_x|=\left| x^{r-1}sin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big) \right| \leq \left| x^{r-1} \right|=\left| x \right|^{r-1}$

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta = \epsilon^{\frac{1}{r-1}}$. Then
$$0<|x|<\delta \implies |d_x-0|<\epsilon$$
Hence, $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=0$. Thus $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=0$.

> *Now, let $r \leq 1$.*

Suppose $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ exists and is equal to $L$.

Then $\exists \delta > 0,$ such that
$$0<|x|<\delta \implies d_x=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=x^{r-1}sin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)=\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)^{1-r}sin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big) \in \bigg(L-\frac{\pi}{(2\pi)^{r}},L+\frac{\pi}{(2\pi)^{r}}\bigg)$$

By Archemedian Property $2,$ $\exists N \in \mathbb{N},$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<2\pi\delta,$ i.e. $\frac{1}{2\pi N}<\delta$

Choose $x_1=\frac{1}{2\pi N}, ~~x_2=\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Then $d_{x_1}=\Big(2\pi N\Big)^{1-r}sin\Big(2\pi N\Big)=0$ and
$d_{x_2}=\Big(2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)^{1-r}sin\Big(2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)=\Big(2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)^{1-r}>(2\pi N)^{1-r} \geq (2\pi)^{1-r}=2\cdot \frac{\pi}{(2\pi)^{r}}$

Thus $|d_{x_2}-d_{x_1}|=d_{x_2}-d_{x_1}=2\cdot \frac{\pi}{(2\pi)^{r}}$

Again $0<x_1,x_2<\delta$. Hence $|d_{x_2}-d_{x_1}|<\Big(L+\frac{\pi}{(2\pi)^{r}}\Big)-\Big(L-\frac{\pi}{(2\pi)^{r}}\Big)=2\cdot \frac{\pi}{(2\pi)^{r}}$

Hence we obtain a contradiction.

> Thus $f$ is differentiable at $0$ if $r>1,$ and is not differentiable at $0$ if $r \leq 1$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: And hence $r$ should be greater than $1$.

Comment: You may give a counter example by taking a sequence tends to $0$ in second case!

Comment: @MANMAID : You're correct. See the accepted answer.

Comment: To find the region of $r$, where diff. holds, you may expand $\sin(1/x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct, except you probably meant $$x_2 = \frac{1}{2\pi N + \frac{\pi}{2}}. $$ The only way to make it shorter would be to not spell out every argument in such detail. At some point you should get used to doing this.

For instance, from $|d_x| \le |x|^{r - 1}$ I would just say $|x|^{r - 1} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and therefore $|d_x| \to 0$. (You should know that $x \mapsto x^{r - 1}$ is continuous and so is $x \mapsto |x|$.)

For the second one, I would write it much shorter:

> Let $x_n = \frac{1}{2\pi n}$ and $y_n = \frac{1}{2\pi n + \pi/2}$. Then $x_n, y_n \to 0$. If $d_x$ were continuous at $x = 0$ then $d_{x_n}, d_{y_n}$ should converge to the same value. But $$d_{x_n} = 0$$ whereas $$d_{y_n} = y_n^{r-1}$$ which diverges if $r < 1$ and is $1$ if $r = 1$. Thus $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $0$ if $r \le 1$.

Comment: That's extremely helpful. Thank you for the correction too.